# Firebase Cloud Messaging: Accessing UI elements in onMessageReceived()

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

In my android app, I use firebase cloud messaging to send some data to app.

When the app receives a message through `onMessageReceived()`, I check whether a `MainActivity` is currently visible (`MainActivity` has a static reference to the currently visible `MainActivity`), and if the activity is visible, I make some modifications to the activity.

Since `onMessageReceived()` is not called in the main thread, I use a `Handler` to execute the code in the main thread.

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    handler.post(new Runnable() {
        //Access UI
    });
}
```

Is there anything wrong with this approach? If not, are there any other ways to update the currently visible UI when a cloud message is received?

Comment: you can send a local broadcast to the Activity with the received message and make some changes there.

Answer (score 2):

You should avoid writing direct code in the `onMessageReceived()` for UI changes in a specific activity. You can channel it through Local broadcast receivers.

When you tend to write code directly in the `onMessageReceived()` your `FirebaseMessagingService` class will get cluttered. For instance if you have 4 different kind of notification data  and each data calls for different activity. Then your code will look something like this :

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if(remoteMessage.getData() != null 
        && remoteMessage.getData().containsKey("notification_type")){
        switch(remoteMessage.getData().containsKey("notification_type")){
            case "type1":
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                    //Access UI for some activity
                    .
                    .
                    .
                });
                break;
            case "type2":
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                     //Access UI for some activity
                    .
                    .
                    .
                });
                break;
            case "type3":
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                     //Access UI for some activity
                    .
                    .
                    .

                });
                break;
            case "type4":
                Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
                handler.post(new Runnable() {
                     //Access UI for some activity
                    .
                    .
                    .

                });
                break;

        }
    }

}
```

Alternatively, if you use local broadcast then your code will be much more modular and organised. Your code will look something like this:

```
@Override
public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    if(remoteMessage.getData() != null 
        && remoteMessage.getData().containsKey("notification_type")){
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("body",messageBody); // Put info that you want to send to the activity
        switch(remoteMessage.getData().containsKey("notification_type")){
            case "type1":
                intent.setAction("ACTION_1") // For activity1
                break;
            case "type2":
                intent.setAction("ACTION_2") //For activity2
                break;
            case "type3":
                intent.setAction("ACTION_3") //For activity3
                break;
            case "type4":
                intent.setAction("ACTION_4") //For activity4
                break;
        }
        sendBroadcast(intent);
    }

}
```

And your activity (eg. activity1) will look something like this:
    private BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onResume();

    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(
            "ACTION_1"); // Put appropriate action string 

    mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            //Get message from intent
            String msg_for_me = intent.getStringExtra("some_msg");
            //Do your UI Changes stuff here.

        }
    };
    //registering our receiver
    this.registerReceiver(mReceiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    this.unregisterReceiver(this.mReceiver);//unregister receiver
}
```

According to me this will help you code your UI changes inside the activity itself and leads you towards a better code management.

Hope it is useful!